# How to connect with NamedPipe with Electron and Angular

Tags: angular, electron, named-pipes

Trying to connect with named-pipe in Angular Service and build in Electron.

I tried `net` socket classes but seems like it is not working as not getting the `console.log` on `data`.

```
  import * as net from 'net';

  const client: net.Socket = net.connect(namedPipePath);
  client.on("data", (d: Buffer) => console.log("connected", d.toString('utf8')));
  client.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
  client.on("end", () => console.log('disconnected from server'));
```

I should get the `console.log("connected", d.toString('utf8')))`

[This is what I am getting in the console when printing client instance after net.connect(namedPipePath)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLclt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't see anything wrong in your implementation. I am not sure if you are writing in the `Socket` as you didn't share that piece of code in your snippet above.

Try below along with your existing code, and believe me your socket will listen to you :)

```
public write(buffer: Buffer): void {
    if (this.client.destroyed) {
      return;
    }
    this.client.write(buffer);
  }
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks for your help.